# What's the maximum amount of RAM Ubuntu 20.04 can support?

Tags: 20.04

Pretty straight forward I simply want to know the maximum specifications of RAM Ubuntu 20.04 can support.

Comment: Enter `sudo dmidecode -t 16` and look under Maximum Capacity.

Comment: Your question really should be how much RAM can your motherboard support? Linux can support more RAM than you can afford to buy unless your name is Elon Musk, Bill Gates or Mark Zuckerburg. My laptop supports 32GB and I just upgraded from 8 to the max. On Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows opened all over the place on three monitors it means 2.95 GB used and 28.3 GB free. Some would call it overkill *shrugs*...

Comment: @Jos Although I agree, OP asked for maximum Ubuntu supports not the particular motherboard he owns now.